# How to show multiple nodes with comments and comment form for each node on one page in Drupal?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-comments, drupal-nodes

To display multiple nodes on a custom page, I used [`node_view_multiple($nodes, $view_mode = 'full')`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.module/function/node_view_multiple/7), but nodes are shown without comments and comment form.

How do I show multiple nodes with comments and a comment form for each node on a custom page?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered solving this with the "Views Module"? It could be a nice and fast solution.

Comment: Unfortunately, Views won't help in my situation.

Answer (score 0):

In custom module use `hook_node_view`:

```
<?php
/**
 * Implements hook_node_view().
 */
function CUSTOM_MODULE_NAME_node_view($node, $view_mode) {
  if ($node->type == 'YOUR_CONTENT_TYPE' && $node->comment != COMMENT_NODE_HIDDEN && $view_mode == 'full' && empty($node->in_preview)) {
    $node->content['comments'] = comment_node_page_additions($node);
  }
}
```